# Have users created automatically when a network site is created

Tags: users, multisite, automation, wp-create-user

Trying to figure out how to have users created automatically when a network site is created.

So currently when a new user registers, their account is created and their network site is created.  That gives that new site one user already (the site's admin).  But when that's created I'd like to also have 3 more users automatically created to each new network site on creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that hooking into `wpmu_new_blog` and then creating the user if it does not exists, and adding that user to the blog being created.
To do so, you will use a  code like this ( only for 1 user) , as a network enabled plugin or on the main theme functions.php

```
add_filter('wpmu_new_blog','wpse_29543_new_blog');

function wpse_29543_new_blog($blogid){
    $user_name="user";
    $user_password="password";
    $user_email="email@gmail.com";
    $role="editor";
    $user_id = username_exists( $user_name );
    if ( !$user_id ) {  
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $user_password, $user_email );
    } 
    add_user_to_blog( $blogid, $user_id, $role );

}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where did you add this code

Comment: I take that back.  It does work.  I just needed to try it when I created the new site.  I was only trying on refresh.  Awesome, thank you!!